# New In-App Purchase - Causing app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have recently released a version of my App that allows in App-Purchases.
I neglected to submit the In-App purchase with my App, so there was no In-App purchase associated with it (in itunes connect).

Now, when opening the App and attempting to open settings (which requires the In-App purchases function to be queried), the App Crashes. I have since submitted the In-App purchases, and want to know if this will resolve my issues?

Below is a crash log, which I really don't know how to interpret sorry!
Any help would be great!

http://pastebin.com/Zf6ViUpw

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the InApp Purchase is not working it can break your app. It really depend on the code, but I suppose you didn't take any precaution for that problem (why you should do that).

You can ask Apple to do an Expedited App Review for your InApp Purchase explaining it is causing serious problem with your App and they will push you up to the review queue.

Follow the link on this page: [App Review](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/).

Comment: Thanks - i'd submitted a Expedited App Review as soon as I noticed the issue, and it actually worked, 1-2 day App Review!